# Assembly output (I did not get it)

Tags: assembly, microprocessors, emu8086

I want to print a single string `computer` on the screen

But my output displays the string twice like this:

```
 computercomputer
```

**My code:**

```
data segment   
mesaj db "computer$"
ends
stack segment
dw   128  dup(0)
ends
code segment
start:
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
call ekransil
lea dx,mesaj    
call yaz
yaz proc
mov ah,09
int 21h
ret
yaz endp
ekransil proc ;create procedur
mov ax,0600h
mov bh,74h
mov cx,0000h
mov dx,184fh
int 10h
ret
ekransil endp
int 20h
end start ;finish program
```

Why does the value display in the data segment print twice? I don't understand. Anybody help me.

Comment: The directives `proc/endp` are lot more just style-sugar for source reader than doing any changes to the outputted machine code, so the position of that code matters. You did put the subroutine code directly into your app code (before the `int 20h` terminating it), thus it gets executed as part of main app second time. Using debugger should make such things obvious, as you will suddenly end executing instructions of the subroutine unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the next instruction to execute after this one `call yaz` ? The following instructions will be executed

```
mov ah,09
int 21h
ret
```

hence you got 2x 'computer' word. After this line `call yaz` you should jump at the end of program or `ret` call.

Did you see it ?

```
 call ekransil
 lea dx,mesaj    
 call yaz         
 ; next instructions to execute are below
 yaz proc
   mov ah,09
   int 21h
   ret
 yaz endp
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid displaying your string twice you can do one of the following:

**Usually Way:**

Add `jmp exit` after `call yaz` and then add these lines before `end start`:

```
exit:
      mov ah, 04ch ; exit the program
      int 21h      ; and return the control to your OS
```

**Prefered Way:**

or you can just place the definitions of both of your procedures after the exit code like this:

```
mov ah, 04ch     ; exit
int 21h          ; code 

yaz proc         ; definition of first procedure 
    mov ah,09
    int 21h
    ret
yaz endp

ekransil proc     ; definition of second procedure
    mov ax,0600h
    mov bh,74h
    mov cx,0000h
    mov dx,184fh
    int 10h
    ret
ekransil endp       

end start         ; finish program
```

Notice that in the preferred version we don't have to `jmp` to label `exit` and to define it. Its prefered than the former because it makes your program look less confusing and you would have all of the definitions of your procedures separate from the main procedure (start). Besides it becomes very helpful for debugging.

Cheers Ahtisham :)